# How to use com components

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

i hav created a COM component using vs2005 .

Now let me know can i use the dll which i have create on vs2005(which uses f/w 2.0) in vs2003(which uses f/w 1.1)??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your real question is wether or not you can mix .NET versions in a single app as long as they use COM to interact.

I believe the answer is "no". An AppDomain can only have one .NET runtime loaded. Multiple runtimes is a feature of .NET 4.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET projects add a reference into the "references" branch of the solution and a `using` directive into each file you want to use that component. In C++ projects use `import` directive.